# Converting smalldatetime datatype to varchar datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert smalldatetime to varchar? I've tried everything from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx, but it didn't work.

I want to convert smalldatetime into varchar, because I want to use it in select like this:

`select 'Some text'+@Date`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

'121' is the format of the date in this case 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h)', 
char(16) is the number of characters you wish to include, first 16 in this case.

```
select 'Some text'+convert(char(16), @date, 121)
```

[Cast and Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CONVERT_TSQL%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1%29;k%28MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT%29;k%28DevLang-TSQL%29&rd=true)

Answer (score 2):

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), YourDateColumn, 103) as NewColumnName

here 103 make the date format as dd/mm/yyyy
if you want mm/dd/yyyy, you have to use 100

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a more up to date link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

The expression

```
'Some text ' + CONVERT(VarChar(20), [Data])
```

works fine, [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6bf02/2), what style did you want?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto

```
DECLARE @FechaDesde datetime2
SET @FechaDesde = ''
SELECT  LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @FechaDesde, 120), 10)
print @FechaDesde
---FECHA HASTA
DECLARE @FechaHasta datetime2
SET @FechaHasta = ''
SELECT  LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @FechaHasta, 120), 10)
print @FechaHasta
SELECT *  from compras where fec_emis between @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta
```